# Вопрос по TelegramBotsApi

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Пробую сделать бота для телеграм, у меня возник следующий вопрос. Вроде как для создания есть библиотека от телеграмм на Java, в который необходимо инициализировать контекст и засунуть туда объект, отнаследовавшийся от TelegramLongPollingBot.

Как я понял он будет со своим токеном в определённый интервал слать запросы к серваку телеграм об обновлении и, при наличии такового, будет вызываться метод OnUpdateReceiving(), который я переопределил в классе Bot.

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

        @Override
        public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

            MessageProcessor processor = new MessageProcessorImpl();
            processor.process(this, update);

        }

        @Override
        public String getBotUsername() {
            return "animehentai_bot";
        }

        @Override
        public String getBotToken() {
            return "672062292:AAGmvmXJV_f-HKqsh3L_OjeKBECzgkVj_cc";
        }

}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, создаётся ли для каждого полученного сообщения новый экземпляр класса Bot или запускается новый поток, или они идут друг за другом как ServerSocket().accept() и необходимо самому реализовывать многопоточность??

Я пытался найти в Google, но вроде как не увидел ничего подобного, буду рад если кто скинет ссылку на доки этой либы или будет добр объяснить этот процесс принятия сообщения.

Comment: видеоинструкция вам подойдет?

Comment: @michael_best, если это не ирония, то да

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZgXUK5L3Ss

Comment: Тут разве не дело, как вы всё это запускаете?